# Relationship between local minimum and global minimum based on metrics

Tags: optimization, metric-spaces, global-optimization

Given a set of points $S \subset X$ with a metric defined $d : X \times X \to \mathbb{R}^+$.

I am  interested in the relationship between $Z = \textbf{argmin}_{z \in X} \sum_{i \in S} d(i, z)$ and $S$.

Here $z \in X$ is the global minimum distance element to $S$, as it is not necessarily unique, I use $Z$ to capture all the possible $z$.

Under what condition would $Z \cap S = \emptyset$ ? Also under what condition $Z \cap S  \neq \emptyset$ ?

For example, if $X$ is the $\mathbb{R}$, and $d$ is the euclidean distance then $Z \cap S \neq \emptyset$. As $Z \cap S$ is simply the median of $S$.

Or if $X$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $d$ is still the euclidean distance, assuming no 3 elements in $S$ is co-linear, then $Z \cap S = \emptyset$. If only $S$ only contains 3 non co-linear element, the $Z$ is Fermat–Torricelli point.

Comment: You circularly use $Z$ in the definition of $Z$; can you clarify the definition there?

Comment: $Z$ is the subset of $X$ such that $\forall z \in Z$, the global minimum distance between $z$ and $S$ is obtained.

Comment: Please, choose carefully the tags. If you read the description of the set-theory tag you'll see that your question doesn't fit that.

Comment: @pengyu Thanks for the clarification.